# Compare differences between two associative 2d arrays and after padding one array with default values, discard rows with no difference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, default-value, array-difference

I'm building a form to do the following:

- Print a table of users and permissions, pulling from MySQL. Each permission a user has is a checked box, and each one they lack is an unchecked box.
- Allow an administrator to check and uncheck boxes to grant or remove permissions.
- When the form is submitted, show a confirmation page with ONLY the users whose permissions will be changed, highlighting the specific changes.
- When the changes are confirmed, modify the database accordingly.

To do this, I'm creating two arrays of user permissions: one according to what the database shows, and one according to what the form shows.

If a user lacks a permission in MySQL, it will be shown as a 0. If they lack a permission in the form submission, it simply won't exist.

Here are two simple examples of the arrays:

#### Database array

```
[User1] => Array ([public] => 1
                [private] => 1
                [secret] => 1
               ) 
[User2] => Array ([public] => 1
                [private] => 0
                [secret] => 0
               )
```

#### Form submission array (revoking "secret" from User1 and giving it to User2)

```
[User1] => Array ([public] => 1
                [private] => 1 
               )

[User2] => Array ([public] => 1
                  [secret] => 1
                 )
```

### Question

How can I **elegantly combine these two arrays** to make a "changes" array, such that:

- Users with identical permissions in both are omitted
- Remaining users have all permissions - public, private and secret - set to either 0 or 1.
- Each permission is 0 if it was missing from the form submission array, and 1 if it was in the form submission array

For example, combining the above would give:

```
[User1] => Array ([public] => 1
                [private] => 1
                [secret] => 0
               ) 
[User2] => Array ([public] => 1
                [private] => 0
                [secret] => 1
               )
```

### Attempts so far

- As a first step, I have tried using array_merge() with the forms array listed second, thinking it would overwrite the database array where they differed. Instead, it deleted elements that differed.
- I have tried setting up a foreach() statement to compare the two arrays, but it's becoming complicated, and I think there must be a simpler way

## UPDATE

Whew! A new answer drew my attention back to this old question. I got this working, but later I scrapped this crazy code - it was way too complicated to go back and work with. Instead, I wrote a PHP back end script to change one permission at a time, then wrote an AJAX front end to send changes over it. Much simpler code, and the changes are instantaneous for the user. A highlight effect gives instant, on-page feedback about what has changed.

Answer (score 2):

The post data only contains the permissions you should grant. So, set up a "baseline" with all the permissions set to 0. Then merge with the submission.

```
$empty_perms = array("public" => 0, "private" => 0, "secret" => 0);

$new_user1_perms = array_merge($empty_perms, $_POST['User1']);
$new_user2_perms = array_merge($empty_perms, $_POST['User2']);
```

Now update the database using the merged arrays. This way you will set correct permissions for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:
[array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you need by referring to the [PHP: Arrays manual](http://www.php.net/array). You've documented the question quite well but I still can't make it out clearly what is it that you need.

Specifically you should be looking at using the array_diff() and array_intersect(), to compute the difference or intersection of two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to combine gnud's solution with comparing by value.
I've added one more key "member" to show zero permission being unchanged.

```
// empty permissions
$empty_perms = array("public" => 0, "private" => 0, "secret" => 0, "member" => 0);

// original permissions (please note that it MUST contain ALL keys)
$old_perms = array("public" => 1, "private" => 0, "secret" => 1, "member" => 0);

// POST data container
$post_data = array("public" => 1, "private" => 1);

// apply new user permissions - put them into db
$new_perms = array_merge($empty_perms, $post_data);

// differences to show
$diff_perms = array();

// compare new and old permissions
foreach($empty_perms as $k => $v) {
    $diff_perms[$k] = (int)($old_perms[$k] !== $new_perms[$k]);
}
```

This example should give you following results (old, new, changes):

```
Array
(
    [public] => 1
    [private] => 0
    [secret] => 1
    [member] => 0
)

Array
(
    [public] => 1
    [private] => 1
    [secret] => 0
    [member] => 0
)

Array
(
    [public] => 0
    [private] => 1
    [secret] => 1
    [member] => 0
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To use `array_diff()` the first argument must be the superset, or the larger of the two arrays. To use `array_diff()` when you are not sure which array is larger simply:

```
  //start with the superset of for array_diff to return differences
  if(count($prev_wholesaler_assignments) > count($wholesalers)){
      $perm_diff = array_diff($prev_wholesaler_assignments,$wholesalers);  
  } elseif (count($prev_wholesaler_assignments) < count($wholesalers)){
      $perm_diff = array_diff($wholesalers,$prev_wholesaler_assignments);
  }
```

This returns the disjunction regardless of which array happens to be larger.

Answer (score 0):

To compare zero-filled rows against database rows:

1. Populate a flat, associative array containing all possible column names with zero values. You might hardcode these values or access them from your first database row.
2. Iterate the form submission data
3. Assuming that all form submissions are found in the database, after padding the submission row with default zeroes, if a user's new data does not contain the same associative data (in any order) then push that row into the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/maXaZ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($form as $user => $row) {
    /*if (!isset($database[$user])) {
        continue;
    }*/
    $new = array_replace($defaults, $row);
    if ($db[$user] != $new) {
        $result[$user] = $new;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if some sort of variation on [differential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371898/how-does-differential-execution-work) would help.