# JavaBeans Comparator/Diff

Tags: java, open-source, apache-commons-beanutils

Is there a library that can compare two javabeans by their properties and tell you the differences between them?

I was thinking this would be something BeanUtils will do but can't find it in the documentation

Basically I want to 'diff' them

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578209/common-algorithm-for-generating-a-diff-of-the-fields-in-two-beans

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no library for this, because it is trivial to implement.
Just use the code from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578209/common-algorithm-for-generating-a-diff-of-the-fields-in-two-beans) that artbristol provided in the comment.