# Is there a way to know which properties are different between two beans?

Tags: java, javabeans

I would like to persist changes made to my beans in a fashion similar to what [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers/) does (but i can't use Envers, as i'm not connected to a JDBC back-end).

So, for that, i would like to know, between two instances of a given bean class, which properties have different values.

To be more clear, when given beans A and B, I would like to have a method ... say ... `diff(A, B)`, that will output me a list (or map) linking properties to their old/new values.

Something like

```
<BeanClass> Collection<Field, Entry<Object, Object> diff(BeanClass a, BeanClass b)
```

Is there a library to do that in the Java world ?

Comment: I think this can be done easily with reflection.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578209/common-algorithm-for-generating-a-diff-of-the-fields-in-two-beans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the solution was to use [java-object-diff](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff/), which provides a visitable tree of differences between objects. As a consequence, we ended up using that library with great success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EqulasBuilder class from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html):

```
String[] Arr = new String[excludedFields.size()]; //Add fields you want to exclude in here

boolean result = EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(object2, object1,Arr);

if(!result){
    System.out.println("----- Failure:" + StringUtils.difference(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toStringExclude(object1,excludedFields),ReflectionToStringBuilder.toStringExclude(object2,excludedFields)));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with Reflection + [Apache Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html). The recursive part will be the tricky one, in case you want to do deep diff.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
of course there's a lot of work to do with reflections (as written by others), this is where you should start.

By the way, I've just found a project that should do what you are looking for, just checkout the trunk from the repository:

https://code.google.com/p/beandiff/source/checkout

Hope that helps

---

Try to look up at Apache [BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.7.0/docs/bean-collections/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html);

> This comparator compares two beans by the specified bean property. It
>   is also possible to compare beans based on nested, indexed, combined,
>   mapped bean properties. Please see the PropertyUtilsBean documentation
>   for all property name possibilities.

```
compare(java.lang.Object o1, java.lang.Object o2)
          Compare two JavaBeans by their shared property.
```

Comment: Well, this one simply tells me how they compare, **not** which of their values differs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
public <T> Map<Field, Entry<Object, Object>> diff(T a, T b){
    //... initialize the map
    for (Method m : a.getClass().getMethods()){
        if(m.getName().startsWith("get")){
            Object obj1 = m.invoke(a, null);
            Object obj2 = m.invoke(b, null);
            if(!obj1.equals(obj2)){
                //converts getName to name, for example
                String fieldName = m.getName()...; 
                map.put(a.getClass().getField(fieldName), new Entry(obj1, obj2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Considering you follow the Java Beans convention.