# Dynamic Windows Forms Components (Performance problem)

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, dynamic, layout

I have a problem with performance of my code under Windows Forms.
Have a form, her layout is depending on constructor data, because he layout must be `OnLoad` or in `Constructor` generated.

I generation is simple, base `FlowLayoutPanel` have other `FlowLayoutPanels`, for each have a `Label` and `TextBox` with `DataBinding`.

Problem is this is VERY SLOW, up to 20 seconds, i drawing less than 100 controls, from `Performace Session` i know a problem is on 70% procesing functions:

1. System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(class System.Windows.Forms.Control)
2. System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.Add(class System.Windows.Forms.Binding)

How i can do with this?
Anyone help me in this problem?
How solve the dynamic form layout problem?

Comment: You have my sympathy. You could use stackshots to tell exactly what the problem is. In general, problems like that are why I use Dynamic Dialogs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371898/how-does-differential-execution-work). I have a version for Windows Forms, and it works fine, but it belongs to my employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently read the this article that has a ton of ideas for optimizing performance in .Net Winforms apps. [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163630.aspx)

Some of those that may apply to your situation are that if you are retrieving the data that you are Databinding the Controls to you may want to spin that off onto a sep. thred from the UI so it can retrieve the Data Asynchronously.

You can do this with the Background Worker class.

Also if only some of the controls are not going to be initially visible you can postpone that work until later.

"Operations that must be performed, but are not needed for displaying the first
"UI, can be done while the system is idle or on demand after the first UI is shown. 
"For example, if you have a TabControl, populate only the topmost page on startup 
"and retrieve the information for other pages when required."

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, but actually on my form all content is visible, but this is good tip for future.

Answer (score 2):

Have you disabled layout while adding the controls?

```
        panel.SuspendLayout();
        try
        {
            // add controls in a loop/etc here
        }
        finally
        {
            panel.ResumeLayout();
        }
```

Comment: Yes i have it, on base panel but application works in same time, if I get this into a form result is same.